# t test for data that is spread on a year based data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame given by the sample below.

```
Counts <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), "2005" = c(0, 1, 3, 2), "2006" = c(1, 0, 2, 1), "2007" = c(3, 1, 6, 4), "2008" = c(2, 1, 11, 3), "2009" = c(6, 0 , 8, 4), ECP = c(2008, 2007, 2007, 2006))
```

ECP stands for the Earliest Collaboration Point and is assigned a year. The rest of the data are the number of patents for a particular company ID per year.

I want to do a t.test to compare the "average patents per year" of the IDs before and after the ECP (collaboration year). I know that I need to carry out a paired-sample t-test since the sample is the same set of companies. I have a manual way to do the t.test where I split the data frame depending on the ECP but since the data frame is a bit huge with 950 IDs and 13 years (variables), I would like a better solution.

Any other ideas for analysis of the data are also welcome.
Kind regards

Comment: Please check the data you created.  There are some issues

Comment: Yes, sorry. Correcting it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you can try

```
# data
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
a1 <- c(0, 1, 3, 2)
a2 <- c(1, 0, 2, 1)
a3 <- c(3, 1, 6, 4)
a4 <- c(2, 1, 11, 3)
a5 <- c(6, 0 , 8, 4) 
ECP <- c(2008, 2007, 2007, 2006)
Counts <- data.frame(ID, "2005"=a1, "2006"=a2, "2007"=a3, "2008"=a4, "2009"=a5, ECP) 

library(tidyverse)
Counts %>% 
  gather(k, v, -ID, -ECP) %>% 
  mutate(k=as.numeric(gsub("X", "", k))) %>% 
  mutate(BA=factor(ifelse(k < ECP, "before", "after"), levels = c("before", "after"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(BA, v)) + 
   geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0) + 
   ggbeeswarm::geom_beeswarm() +
   ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("before", "after")), test = "t.test")
```

[image]

Or this?

```
Counts %>% 
  gather(k, v, -ID, -ECP) %>% 
  mutate(k=as.numeric(gsub("X", "", k))) %>% 
  mutate(BA=factor(ifelse(k < ECP, "before", "after"), levels = c("before", "after"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(k), v, fill = BA)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group=BA))
```

[image]

but as you see in the second picture there is not enough data to calculate a t.test.

Comment: The 1st set of code and in particular, the first few lines until the plot function have helped me proceed. 
Just a small question about the working; do k and v represent "key" and "value"?

For the second set, plotting per year is not that useful for my analysis. 

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JGG yes k and v represent "key" and "value". you can name it like whatever you want.